# SvelteKit: <svelte:window> bindings don't work

Tags: web, server-side-rendering, svelte, sveltekit

So this is one of my first questions on StackOverflow.
I have been stuck with trying to bind a variable to the window's inner height.

**Context:**
I have a website comprised of 3 main elements in this order:

1. Header
2. Content
3. Navbar (fixed)

What I want is to find the height of the space between the header and the navbar.
For this I am trying to bind a variable to the window's inner height, and then subtract the header and navbar heights which are known.

What I find strange is that none of the other bindings on svelte:window seem to work either.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<script>
import { navHeight, headerHeight, contentHeight } from "$lib/stores/dimensions.js"

let innerHeight = 0;
// write the computed height in the store
$: $contentHeight = innerHeight - $navHeight - $headerHeight;

</script>

<!-- Get the window's inner height and bind the innerHeight variable to it -->
<svelte:window bind:innerHeight />
<p>{innerHeight}</p>
```

Comment: My understanding is that the `<svelte:window>` object is oriented to adding event listeners to the window on a component by component basis, but maybe you could use some global css to lay this out instead? It would still be responsive that way. A quick search for "svelte global css" should give you plenty of examples. I've had some luck with global CSS properties to do the same thing, and you could bind a listener for resize and `onMount` to check the size and set the variable in a store.

Comment: If I just remove all the parts related to the stores (since I have no idea how they look like) and just keep the `innerHeight` and the binding, this works perfectly fine.  Looks to me like your error is somewhere else.

Comment: Could you please provice a simple [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world)?

Comment: @johannchopin that's just it, I cannot reproduce the issue when I use REPL ([here is a REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/aa24e0b95bad4d06a5c8d0d051b521b4?version=3.29.4) that is showing what I want)

Comment: @StephaneVanraes Yes exactly, even when I take everything out and just keep the _innerHeight_ variable, I cannot seem to be able to bind it to <svelte:window>

Comment: @NikP Yes I will probably end up using CSS variables in the meantime, but I would still want to know why this is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the solution to my problem: I was trying to place this code in **__layout.svelte**. Once I placed this code in the index page everything worked as intended!

Apparently layouts are not capable of accessing the window properties (understandable though, since it's supposed to be used as a template).

Comment: Since you answered your own question (which is encouraged btw) you should mark your answer as the selected answer. I didn't know it needed to be in `__layout` myself and didn't have the time to play with it and figure it out, so thanks for chasing it down. Now I know and hopefully this helps others as well.